# "Increase of" versus "increase in"

Tags: word-choice

A. Our system can detect a sudden increase of water levels.

B. Our system can detect a sudden increase in water levels.

Which sentence would you say sounds more natural? Are they both actually correct?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***a sudden increase in water levels*** is the (only) correct one.

You would use **of** to describe the *magnitude* of the increase, e.g. ***an increase of 10 percent***.

See more examples here:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/increase